# command 'paste and indent.action' not found in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, command

I installed a VS Code extension called *paste-and-indent* in an attempt to replicate Sublime Text's formatting behavior when copy-pasting code. I then added the following keybindings to the keybinding.json file as instructed:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+v",
    "command": "pasteAndIndent.action",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+v",
    "command": "editor.action.clipboardPasteAction",
    "when": "!editorTextFocus"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+v",
    "command": "editor.action.clipboardPasteAction",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
}
```

But when I try to paste with ctrl+v it doesn't even paste anything and the following error message pops up: `command 'paste and indent.action' not found in VS Code`. Tried searching the error, haven't seen anything remotely similar.

Answer (score 1):

Use `editor.action.clipboardPasteAction` instead of `pasteAndIndent.action`

Comment: I don't know why,but this work. "pasteAndIndent.action" work on mac,but linux. "editor.action.clipboardPasteAction" do all work.

Answer (score 0):

Correct the plugin command:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+v",
  "command": "extension.paste-indent",
  "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
}
```